# certMgr.exe not loading the private key of certificate in personal local machine store(Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows, ssl

I have an application which runs certmgr.exe to install certificates at localMachine in root and personal folder. Following are the commands I am using

```
CertMgr.exe -add -all "secure\certs\cacert.crt" -s -r localMachine root
CertMgr.exe -add -all "secure\certs\server.p12" -s -r localMachine my
```

When I run these commands via command prompt to install these certificates respectively in windows7/8 platform, certificates get install and they work

But when I run the same command on windows 10 platform, certificates get installed in store but they don't work. Following error comes:

> ERROR  :-2506:Load device private key 'CN=ABB Authentication Server, OU=CSA, O=ABB' from windows store 'MY' failed
>   ERROR  :-2506:Cannot load private key/certificate pair from Windows store

Certificates are proper, I verified this by manually importing the certificates in mmc. When I imported manually, they started working. Clearly I could find that there is some problem with certmgr.exe  or the access rights in windows 10 platform. I tried with different *"certmgr.exe's"* but could not solve the problem.

Comment: nice question but you are done with it or not?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

Following code worked for me in .Net:

```
Dim store As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
store.Open(X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
Dim cert As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("c:\cert.pfx", "password")
store.Add(cert)
store.Close()
```

Comment: sorry to say but I tried the same as well. Made my own certificate installer . here is the code:

Comment: var store = new X509Store(locName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
         store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
         string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + certName;
         store.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet));
         store.Close();

Comment: are you running this code with administrator right, because my code is working with admin rights, and you can try to use user's StoreLocation instead of LocalMachine.

Comment: made it working by adding an attribute to the code:'   store.Add(new X509Certificate2(path, empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet));'

Answer (score 0):

Try to run CertMgr.exe from cmd, with **Run As Administrator** option by right clicking cmd app, from system32 folder.

Comment: Tried that also, Not working. One thing is clear , "certMgr.exe" is not importing the private key of the certificate , though it is installing the certificate but private key is not getting bind. there must be some access problem or something for windows 10.